# Is this a reasonable way to design this DynamoDB table? Alternatives?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

Our team has started to use AWS and one of our projects will require storing approval statuses of various recommendations in a table.

There are various things that identify a single recommendation, let's say they're : `State, ApplicationDate, LocationID, and Phase`. And then a bunch of attributes corresponding to the recommendation (title, volume, etc. etc.)

The use case will often require grabbing all entries for a given `State` and `ApplicationDate` (and then we will look at all the LocationId and Phase items that correspond to it) for review from a UI. Items are added to the table one at a time for a given `Station, ApplicationDate, LocationId, Phase` and updated frequently.

A dev with a little more AWS experience mentioned we should probably use `State+ApplicationDate` as the partition key, and `LocationId+Phase` as the sort key. These two pieces combined would make the primary key. I generally understand this, but how does that work if we start getting multiple recommendations for the same primary key? I figure we either are ok with just overwriting what was previously there, OR we have to add some other attribute so we can write a recommendation for the `State+ApplicationDate/LocationId+Phase` multiple times and get all previous values if we need to... but that would require adding something to the primary key right? Would that be like adding some kind of unique value to the sort key? Or for example, if we need to do status and want to record different values at different statuses, would we just need to add status to the sort key?

Does this sound like a reasonable approach or should I be exploring a different NAWS offering for storing this data?

Comment: See the Modeling guide here for information about best practices. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/prescriptive-guidance/latest/dynamodb-data-modeling/dynamodb-data-modeling.pdf

Comment: There can be only one record for a given primary key. So, there cannot be multiple records for a given combination of attributes constituting the primary key. Also, including `ApplicationDate` in the partition key may result in only one partition getting hammered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a time-based id property, such as a ULID or KSID. This will provide randomness to avoid overwriting data, but also provide a time-based sorting of your data when used as part of a sort key

Because the id value is random, you will want to add it to your sort key for the table or index where you perform your list operations, and reserve the pk for known values that can be specified exactly.

It sounds like the 'State' is a value that can change. You can't update an item's key attributes on the table, so it is more common to use these attributes in a key for a GSI if they are needed to list data.

Given the above, an alternative design is to use the LocationId as the pk, the random id value as the sk, and a GSI with the GSI with 'State' as the pk and the random id as the sk. Or, if you want to list the items by State -> Phase -> date, the GSI sk could be a concatenation of the Phase and id property. The above pattern gives you another list mechanism using the LocationId + timestamp of the recommendation create time.